# Powershell console tell host its still alive

Tags: powershell

I'm searching the hole HDD with GCI -recurse and after that I'm working with the result...
what do I have to do, to let the console tell me its still alive?
like GCI C:\ -recurse blabla .... |every 2minutes write-host "im still searching"

Edit:

```
$File = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
| where {$_.PsIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.CreationTime -le "$OldDate"} 
| select -Property name,Fullname 
| write-progress -activity "Searching..." -Status "Please wait..." -percentcomplete ???
```

$Path has a lot of files and folders, will take some days to complete this task
How can I calculate percentcomplete? If I use count, it would count all items first?!
It would be also ok, if it counts the files proceeded like:

```
if($countfiles -ge "10000")
{write-Host "Still working, currently $_"}
else {$countfiles=$countfiles+1}
```

Comment: It will not be that easy, Powershell will try to load alot to memory which you can monitor by task manager. It's better to exclude some pathes or split the process to crawl through your folders seperately

Comment: Depends what you are doing. If you are storing the output into a variable, then yes that will consume a lot of memory. If you use the pipeline and discard the output immediately then it might be less memory-intensive.

Comment: Or you could start it as a job, and every once in a while do a Get-Job to see if it's still running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will write status messages for status and pass the child items down the pipeline. The write-host can be replaced with whatever processing you actually want to do with the child items

```
get-childitem -recurse| %{write-progress -Status $_ -Activity "Trawling...";$_} | %{write-host $_}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -recurse -verbose
```

or am i missing something in the question?